# Is $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}])$ a lattice in $SL_2(\mathbb{R}) \times SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ for all d?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, lattices-in-lie-groups

Let $d > 0$ be a square-free integer.

If $d \equiv 2,3 \text{ mod } 4$,  then $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ is the ring of integers of the number field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{d})$. We can thus consider the two maps $i_1, i_2 \colon \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}] \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $x + y\sqrt{2} \mapsto x \pm y \sqrt{2}$ and the image of the induced map
$$
SL_2(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]) \hookrightarrow SL_2(\mathbb{R}) \times SL_2( \mathbb{R})
$$
is a lattice.

Does this also hold for the case $d \equiv 1 \text{ mod } 4$, where $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]$ is in general *not* a ring of integers of a number field anymore?

Comment: The image of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}]) \hookrightarrow SL_2(\mathbb{R}) \times SL_2( \mathbb{R})$ is a discrete subgroup because $\sqrt{d}$ is an algebraic integer so the image of $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{d}] \hookrightarrow\Bbb{R}^2$ is discrete. Are you asking if it is cocompact ?

Comment: @reuns Interesting. Lattice for me means discrete+finite covolume, so that leaves the question whether it has finite covolume to me.

Comment: I believe the answer is yes, more generally for any order. One can cook up a finite map in between induced by inclusion.

Comment: I'd say $SL_2(Z)$ isn't cocompact in $SL_2(R)$ because it misses $\pmatrix{a & 0 \\ 0 & a^{-1}}$. How would you approach $ \pmatrix{a & 0 \\ 0 & a^{-1}} \times \pmatrix{1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1} \in SL_2(R) \times SL_2(R)$ with elements in $SL_2(Z[\sqrt{d}])$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure; if $A$ is the ring of integers of a number field and $B$ is an order then $\mathrm{SL}_2(B)$ has finite index in the version for $A$, since it contains the kernel of the map to the finite group $\mathrm{SL}_2(A/N)$ for some $N$ since $B$ will contain $NA$ where $N$ is the index. Of course you need to know that $\mathrm{SL}_2(A)$ is a lattice in $\mathrm{SL}_2(A \otimes \mathbf{R})$ which you implicitly seem to know but is also in standard books on arithmetic groups like the one by Dave Morris.

Comment: So for example, $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}])$ has finite index in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}[(1+\sqrt(5))/2])$ (which we know is a lattice in $SL_2(\mathbb{R})^2$) because $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ is an order in the ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}[(1+\sqrt{5})/2]$?

Comment: I don't quite understand why $B$ contains $NA$, where $N := [A : B]$ I suppose. Would be great if you could add some details here for me to follow.

Comment: Yes to first comment. For second: $A/B$ is an additive group of order $N$ so it follows by Lagrange.